# Breakpoints on ARM

Tags: arm, breakpoint

Recently I read that breakpoints on ARM are enforced by either using `BKPT` instructions or by using instructions that are defined as invalid.

1. Which method does gdb use?
2. Do you know of any online assemblers for ARM code?(eg: Id like to assemble the `BKPT` instruction and see the bytes corresponding to it, but I dont have qemu/SoC chips handy). What do you use?

Answer (score 1):

1) This depends on whether your are in THUMB or ARM mode, as these have different opcode sets. [This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345371/how-do-i-set-a-software-breakpoint-on-an-arm-processor) might be relevant.

2a) I don't know any online assemblers for ARM, but for single instructions, i find [this table](http://imrannazar.com/ARM-Opcode-Map) handy.

2b) If you want to assemble larger chunks of code, probably the easiest method to get a working ARM assembler is installing the Android NDK, which has toolchains for various processors including x86, arm, and mips. As i'm using Ubuntu, my arm assembler is $ndk-root/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-as; on windows, i'd assume a .exe file should be in a similar location. My answer to [this question](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9094/offset-calculation-for-branch-instruction-in-arm/9096#9096) shows how to use arm-as and arm-objdump to get the hex bytes quickly.