# How to modify arm .so?

Tags: ida, arm, android

I want to modify android app writen on c++.

It stores its code mostly in .so file. The code is compiled for arm architecture.

When  I open it in IDA it says that it can only read but modify.

But I need to inject one arm command. How can I do this?

Comment: With regard to your file-system, are you sure you have write-access to the file?

Comment: @JasonGeffner yes. It looked like ida pro doesn't support modyfing arm .so

Comment: Eresi is an option. Also there is hteditor which is capable I believe. And more recently the radare project

Comment: You can modify the .so, it's just that IDA doesn't assemble ARM commands. You can use gnu as and objdump to translate your assembly to hex, then hex edit your .so, as detailed in [this answer](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9094/offset-calculation-for-branch-instruction-in-arm/9096#9096).

Comment: ida patcher from that answer is something I need https://thesprawl.org/projects/ida-patcher/