# Calculating branch in arm64

Tags: arm

I stumbled across this question here [Offset calculation for branch instruction in ARM](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9094/offset-calculation-for-branch-instruction-in-arm)

After understanding all of that, i'm interested in knowing how i can do the same for ARM64/ARMv8 architecture?

Comment: Do you have access to an instruction manual?